# Help With Merge Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, merge

I am wanting to compare the `Distinct sn` from `HMI_Temp` to `sn` in my table `HMI` -> if the `sn` exists, I want to update the values - got this syntax CHECK! - if the `sn` does **NOT** exist, I want to insert the data from `HMI_Temp` into `HMI` I have tried this syntax, but I get errors of:

> Invalid column name 'cb'
>   Invalid column name 'lp'
>   
> Invalid column name cn
>   
> Invalid column name stn

And this is my syntax - how should I re-write this to accomplish my desired result?

```
MERGE INTO HMI AS Target
USING (SELECT DISTINCT sn FROM HMI_Temp) AS Source ON Target.sn = Source.sn
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (lp, cb, cn, sn, stn) VALUES (Source.lp, Source.cb, Source.cn, Source.sn, Source.stn);
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HMI_Temp]
(
    [sID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    stn [float] NULL,
    [sn] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [cn] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [lp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [cb] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [sID] ASC
    ) WITH 
      (
           PAD_INDEX = OFF
         , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
         , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
         , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
         , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
      ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]  
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[HMI_Temp] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[HMI_Temp] ([sID], stn, [sn], [cn], [lp], [cb]) 
VALUES (1, 8888, N'Test', N'Test', N'Test123', N'Test456')
VALUES (1, 8888, N'SecondTest', N'SecondTest', N'SecondTest123', N'SecondTest456')
GO
```

This is the update statement I was using that worked, but now throwing a wrench in it for the insert if not exists :(

```
UPDATE y
SET y.lp = x.lp
,y.cb = x.cb
,y.cn = x.cn
FROM HMI y
INNER JOIN HMI_Temp x
ON y.stn = x.stn
AND y.sn = x.sn
AND y.cn = x.cn
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid the syntax error, you need to include all columns in the `USING` clause that are being inserted into the target table.  So a syntactically valid merge statement would be:

```
MERGE INTO HMI AS Target
USING (SELECT DISTINCT sn, lp, cb, cn, stn FROM HMI_Temp) AS Source ON Target.sn = Source.sn
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (lp, cb, cn, sn, stn) VALUES (Source.lp, Source.cb, Source.cn, Source.sn, Source.stn);
```

Since your intended functionality includes the ability to update existing rows, you also need a `WHEN MATCHED` clause that sets the desired columns in the target table to those values from the source table.  Something like:

```
MERGE INTO HMI AS Target
USING (
    SELECT DISTINCT sn
        , lp
        , cb
        , cn
        , stn 
    FROM HMI_Temp
    ) AS Source ON Target.sn = Source.sn
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Target.lp = Source.lp
    , Target.cb = Source.cb
    , Target.cn = Source.cn
    , Target.stn = Source.stn
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (lp, cb, cn, sn, stn) 
VALUES (Source.lp, Source.cb, Source.cn, Source.sn, Source.stn);
```

However, as mentioned by Aaron in his answer, `MERGE` is fraught with other potential issues.

---

I used the following [minimally complete, verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example):

```
USE tempdb;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.HMI;
CREATE TABLE dbo.HMI
(
    sID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , stn float NULL
    , sn nvarchar(255) NULL
    , cn nvarchar(max) NULL
    , lp nvarchar(max) NULL
    , cb nvarchar(max) NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
      (
          sID ASC
      ) WITH 
        (
            PAD_INDEX = OFF
            , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
            , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
            , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
            , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT dbo.HMI (stn, sn, cn, lp, cb) 
VALUES (8888, N'Test', N'Test', N'Test123', N'Test456')
    , (8887, N'A', N'B', N'C', N'D');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.HMI_Temp;
CREATE TABLE dbo.HMI_Temp
(
    sID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    , stn float NULL
    , sn nvarchar(255) NULL
    , cn nvarchar(max) NULL
    , lp nvarchar(max) NULL
    , cb nvarchar(max) NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
      (
          sID ASC
      ) WITH 
        (
            PAD_INDEX = OFF
            , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
            , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
            , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
            , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 
TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT dbo.HMI_Temp (stn, sn, cn, lp, cb) 
VALUES (8888, N'Test', N'F', N'G', N'H')
```

The data looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.HMI;
```

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ sID ║ stn  ║  sn  ║  cn  ║   lp    ║   cb    ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║   1 ║ 8888 ║ Test ║ Test ║ Test123 ║ Test456 ║
║   2 ║ 8887 ║ A    ║ B    ║ C       ║ D       ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.HMI_Temp;
```

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════╦════╦════╦════╗
║ sID ║ stn  ║  sn  ║ cn ║ lp ║ cb ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬════╬════╬════╣
║   1 ║ 8888 ║ Test ║ F  ║ G  ║ H  ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════╩════╩════╩════╝
```

The merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.HMI AS Target
USING (
    SELECT DISTINCT sn
        , lp
        , cb
        , cn
        , stn 
    FROM dbo.HMI_Temp
    ) AS Source ON Target.sn = Source.sn
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.lp = Source.lp
        , Target.cb = Source.cb
        , Target.cn = Source.cn
        , Target.stn = Source.stn
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (lp, cb, cn, sn, stn) 
    VALUES (Source.lp, Source.cb, Source.cn, Source.sn, Source.stn);
```

The results, post `MERGE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.HMI;
```

```
╔═════╦══════╦══════╦════╦════╦════╗
║ sID ║ stn  ║  sn  ║ cn ║ lp ║ cb ║
╠═════╬══════╬══════╬════╬════╬════╣
║   1 ║ 8888 ║ Test ║ F  ║ G  ║ H  ║
║   2 ║ 8887 ║ A    ║ B  ║ C  ║ D  ║
╚═════╩══════╩══════╩════╩════╩════╝
```

If the `dbo.HMI_Temp` table contains non-unique rows, as in:

```
INSERT dbo.HMI_Temp (stn, sn, cn, lp, cb) 
VALUES (8888, N'Test', N'F', N'G', N'H')
    , (8888, N'Test', N'I', N'J', N'K')
    , (8888, N'Test', N'L', N'M', N'N');
```

When you run the `MERGE` statement, you'll see this error:

> Msg 8672, Level 16, State 1, Line 67
>   The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Since you've now clarified that you also need to use the `cn` column as a uniquifier, you might be able to use this merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.HMI AS Target
USING (
    SELECT sn
        , lp
        , cb
        , cn
        , stn 
    FROM dbo.HMI_Temp
    ) AS Source ON Target.sn = Source.sn
        AND Target.cn = Source.cn
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.lp = Source.lp
        , Target.cb = Source.cb
        , Target.cn = Source.cn
        , Target.stn = Source.stn
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (lp, cb, cn, sn, stn) 
    VALUES (Source.lp, Source.cb, Source.cn, Source.sn, Source.stn);
```

Notice, I added `AND Target.cn = Source.cn` to the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 5):

Here is at least a part of the problem: If you have two rows in `HMI_Temp` with the same value for `sn` but different values for `cb` (or any other column), which one should SQL Server pick?

Here is a better pattern than `MERGE`, IMHO, which [has all kinds of issues](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/):

```
INSERT dbo.HMI(stn,sn,cn,lp,cb)
SELECT stn,sn,cn,lp,cb
FROM
(
  SELECT stn,sn,cn,lp,cb,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY sn,cn -- makes sn + cn distinct
      ORDER BY sID       -- picks which row to keep
    )
  FROM dbo.HMI_Temp
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.HMI WHERE sn = hmi.sn
  )
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This is taking the row with the lowest `sID` but you may wish to rank the rows a different way or use `MIN`/`MAX` on each of the other four columns to determine which row you want to keep. Hard to tell from your question.